# UKCAT math question. Please help.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, ratio

Team.  Won.  Drawn.  Lost.  Points

...A ...... 2 ........ 2 .........           0.......        26

...B ......          1 ........         3 .........           1 ........         18

...C ......          0 ........          3 .........          3 .......        18

...D ......           1 ........         2 .........          1 .......         19

...E ......          2 ........           1 ........          0 ........        21

Q) Given that each team  plays the others TWICE,  if all the remaining matches are draws, what fractions of the teams will have Less than 30 points?

So far I ve figured out that the points earned from a draw is 5, and that there are 9 matches left to play (since 20 is the total and 11 are already played from the table). 
I also worked out that the maximum overall points from the 20 matches (for all the teams) put together is 192. I m not sure if that was of any use though.

But I still can't seem to understand how to get the final scores for all the teams.
Can anyone help me with that.

Thanks in advance :)

PS. I know this looks like a really easy question but I'm really having a hard time grasping it, so your help is more than appreciated

Edit: [Here is the link to the question,](https://books.google.co.ke/books?id=Sk1-3ZlkhbgC&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=if%20all%20the%20remaining%20matches%20are%20drawn,%20what%20fraction%20of%20the%20teams%20will%20have%20less%20than%2030%20points%3F&source=bl&ots=4jzzVLMLHF&sig=MEIYGY25Lh6Vf-APyDX56hlpba0&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=if%20all%20the%20remaining%20matches%20are%20drawn%2C%20what%20fraction%20of%20the%20teams%20will%20have%20less%20than%2030%20points%3F&f=false) it shows the table more clearly and has the complete set of questions

Comment: The Win column adds up to 6, but the Lost column adds up to 5. Also, the Drawn column adds up to an odd number. Is there a problem with the data?

Comment: I don't know if theres a problem with the data because it's from a ukcat book. But I also thought that at first and then I just went ahead to add up all the matches From the win, draw and lost. I got an even number (22) which I divided by 2 to get the actual number of matches played.

Comment: if each team plays others twice then each team plays $8$ matches, that means for team $(A,B,C,D,E)$ remaining matches are $(4,4,5,5,5)$, if each of the remaining matches is a draw then team $(A,B,C,D,E)$ earn $(20,20,25,25,25)$ points, that makes all the teams with more than $30$ points

Comment: @Vikram I'm not sure how you reached the conclusion of the teams ( A, B, C, D, E,) remaining with (4,4,5,5,5)  matches? I only got 9 matches remaining. Please explain how you got those many remaining matches?

Comment: From the link to the question it's clear that the results for team B are wrong and should be B 0 4 1 21.

Comment: @Pink_NinjaTurtle, there are $5$ teams, if each team plays other teams twice then each team plays total $8$ matches, $A$ has already played $2+2=4$ matches, so will play $8-4=4$ more matches and so for other teams. (but I think some problem with the question itself)

Comment: @nickgard Thanks for the clarification. But given that, can there still be a team with a final score of less than 30? Also what method will you use to find the final scores, since i am more interested in learning how to solve such problems rather than getting a final answer for this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve the following system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}2x+2y&=26\\x+3y+z&=18\\3y+3z&=18 \\ x+2y+z&=19 \\ 2x+y&=21\end{cases}$$

By evaluating this you can notice, that this system is contradictory (equations for A and E suggest, that $y=5$, but for B and D shows, that $y=-1$)